# linux 64bit jq did not support the variable with blank space expansion in select function

Tags: linux, bash, x86-64, jq

## Example OK in macos:

### jq Version

```
jq-1.6
```

### Code

```
a='[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d c"}]'
b="d c"
echo $a|jq '.[]|select(.c == "'$b'")'
```

### Output

```
{
  "c": "d c"
}
```

## Example KO in linux:

### jq Version

```
jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe
```

### Code

```
a='[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d c"}]'
b="d c"
echo $a|jq '.[]|select(.c == "'$b'")'
```

### Output

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting QQSTRING_TEXT or QQSTRING_INTERP_START or QQSTRING_END (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[]|select(.c == "d
jq: 1 compile error
```

As above, there is a difference about blank space expand in select function of jq between linux env and macos env. I had already tried to download jq-1.6 in linux env, but it also produced the issue like above example KO in linux. Is there a bug still exist in jq of linux version? And can anybody come in another pretty good way to achieve above functionality? I am using jq in shell to parse the database information getting specify content...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: check your script with shellcheck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a space in the value of `$b`. Thus, when expanded you end up with two arguments to jq, one being `.[]|select(.c == "d` and the other one being `c")`.

If you wanted to properly inject the variable with whitespace, quote the shell variable(s):

```
echo "$a" | jq '.[]|select(.c == "'"$b"'")'
```

Better yet, don't inject data into code, use the idiomatic way to import strings into jq with the dedicated `--arg` option:

```bash
echo "$a" | jq --arg b "$b"  '.[]|select(.c == $b)'
```

Comment: However, there is an another case that like `echo "$a" | jq --arg b "$b"  '.[]|select(.c == "xxx "$b)'` I want to know the correct usage. Could you help to correct?  I want instantly concatenate string and jq variable to a new string during using jq, but I found `select(.c == "xxx "$b)` is error. If I use the way of quoting the shell variable, that is `echo "$a" | jq -r  '.[]|select(.c == "xxx '$b'")'`, it will work fine.

Comment: @YayongDuan There are many ways, here are three of them: `jq --arg b "xxx $b" '.[]|select(.c == $b)'` OR `jq --arg b "$b" '.[]|select(.c == "xxx " + $b)'` OR `jq --arg b "$b" '.[]|select(.c == "xxx \($b)")'`.

Comment: Would you mind tell me why there is a `\` before `(` in last example?

Comment: @YayongDuan Do you mean the backslash before parens as part of a string `"\(...)"`? It's called [string interpolation](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation%3A%5C%28exp%29).

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks for your kindly explanation. :)